# How can I feature detect carousel <select> tags?

Tags: javascript, html, mobile, html-select

I have a `<select>` tag that I'm using the native behavior for on both desktop and mobile. On desktop it does a dropdown; on iPhone it does a carousel. Now I'd like to make it so that small and medium devices that don't have carousels for dropdowns use a menu dialog instead. Is it possible to feature detect carousels?

Comment: I don’t think that’s what 'carousel' means, but I understand the question. No, I don’t think this is something you can feature-detect. `select` elements are almost always rendered using native functionality (e.g. you can't usually style the `option` elements anyway). Best you can do is probably check the user agent string for iOS/iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

There has been extensive work done to detect the device that a website is executing in.

The process for detection centers around a best guess based on the feature set examined.

You will need to include the set of features that identify an iPhone (or other mobile devices) to the specificity that makes sense for your needs.

These can include gesture features, touch features, certain audio and video features, camera features, etc.

Comment: I'm not sure this counts as an answer to the question. Are you saying that carousels can't be feature detected?

Comment: I am saying they can, but in order to get to the granularity you want, it will take a custom set of features to get there. Look into which devices you want to detect, and then choose a feature set based on that.

Comment: My understanding is that if you're not detecting the feature directly, then it isn't "feature detection". I'd rather avoid browser sniffing and if I have to, I'd rather just show a custom menu on all devices.

Comment: That isn't true on the web. Microsoft, Paypal, Amazon... all the major tech companies use feature sets as device indicators. There is no way to directly detect the carousel as it is an operating system feature of iOS. You can only do your best to ensure that the environment has a carousel available.